# Parse a log file into separate column files

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, interview-questions

This is a follow-up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194832/converting-json-based-log-into-column-format-i-e-one-file-per-column .

My task is to optimize this code whose function is to convert the content of this JSON-formatted log file to columnar-formatted `.txt` file for each column. An example for a log file is:

```
{"timestamp": "2022-01-14T00:12:21.000", "Field1": 10, "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0}}
{"timestamp": "2022-01-18T00:15:51.000", "Field_Doc": {"f1": 0, "f2": 1.7, "f3": 2}}
```

It will generate 5 files:

1. `timestamp.column`
2. `Field1.column`
3. `Field_Doc.f1.column`
4. `Field_Doc.f2.column`
5. `Field_Doc.f3.column`

The column file format is as follows:

- string fields are separated by a new line `'\n'` character. Assume that no string value contains new line characters, so no need to worry about escaping them
- double, integer & boolean fields are represented as a single value per line
- null, undefined & empty strings are represented as an empty line

Example content of timestamp.column:

```
2022-01-14T00:12:21.000
2022-01-18T00:15:51.000
```

Note: The fields in the log will be dynamic, do not assume that these are the expected properties.

My current code for this is:

```
import json
import os
def flatten_dict(data, prefix=""):
    result = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if prefix:
           key = prefix + "." + key        
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result.update( flatten_dict(value, key) )
        else:            
            if value is None:
                result[key] = "\n"           
            elif value is "":
                result[key] = "\n"
            else:
                result[key] = value
    return result

path = input("Enter the path for the log file: ")
# Checking if path exists to the selected log
assert os.path.exists(path), "I did not find the file at, "+str(path)
file_obj = open(path)   # emulate file in memory

for line in file_obj:
    data = json.loads(line) 
    data = flatten_dict(data)
    for key, value in data.items():
        with open(key + '.column', "a") as f:
            f.write(str(value) + "\n")
```

This code is currently very slow. It takes about 45 min just to parse 256mb of data which should have taken about 30sec or max a minute.

Can anyone guide me how can I optimize the efficiency? Also how can I print the usage of CPU and RAM for the same? File size to parse may vary up to 2 GB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are the columns separated into different files? This is a strange and inconvenient format. Do you control this?

Comment: i don't control this, I'm just asked to do this

Comment: Is it work, homework, an interview problem, or a programming challenge?

Comment: programming challenge

Comment: No, it's not: [it's an interview question](https://github.com/sparsh459/File-content-convertor-tool/blob/30e2792cb184bbc724dc13763df7c5ff10990175/MCQdb_Developer_Project.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You're re-opening the column files every line. Open them once and then look the file handles up by key.

```py
file_obj = open(path)   # emulate file in memory

for line in file_obj:
    data = json.loads(line) 
    data = flatten_dict(data)
    for key, value in data.items():
        with open(key + '.column', "a") as f:
            f.write(str(value) + "\n")
```

becomes ( not tested )

```py
column_files = {}

with open(path) as jsonl_file:
    for line in jsonl_file:
        data = json.loads(line) 
        data = flatten_dict(data)
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key not in column_files:
                column_files[key] = open(key+'.column','w')

            column_files[key].write(str(value) + "\n")

for f in column_files: f.close()
```

Comment: Instead of using a dict of file handles, you can use a `contextlib.ExitStack`. Also the last line should be `for f in column_files.values(): f.close()`.